# Bootstrap 4.2.1 Flex-box layout column overflowing browser edge

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Using **flex-basis** for column widths. Why does COLUMN02 extend beyond the browser's edge? What am I doing wrong? Unfortunately it does not show in the code snippets here but it does in the the fiddle. TIA!

http://jsfiddle.net/dragontheory/37b8vkoa/1/

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* force footer to bottom of browser */
  height: 100%;
  /*for IE11*/
}

.page-header,
.page-footer {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.column01 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0 0 200px;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 200px;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.column02 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column px-0">
  <div class="page-footer p-2">HEADER</div>
  <main class="row flex-fill no-gutters flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col column01 d-flex flex-column">COLUMN01</div>
    <div class="col column02 d-flex flex-column">COLUMN02</div>
  </main>
  <div class="page-footer p-2">FOOTER</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your custom CSS that's causing it:

```
 .column02 {
   flex: 0 0 auto;
 }
 .col {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

... which translates into:

- `flex-grow: 0` (do not allow flex to grow this element)
- `flex-shrink: 0` (do not allow flex to shrink this element)
- `flex-basis: auto` (get `flex-basis` from `width` - which is set to `100%` by `.col`)

Which blocks the `width` of that column to the `width` of its parent and does not allow it to shrink down, regardless of the fact the sum of the children's `width`s exceeds the `width` of the parent.

Setting ***any*** of the following on `.column02` will fix it:

- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `width: auto; flex-grow: 1;`
- `flex-basis: 0; flex-grow: 1;`
- `flex: 1;`

Or simply [remove `flex: 0 0 auto;`](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/4w3mq6ap/) (because `.col` already sets `flex-basis: 0; flex-grow: 1;` - third case above).

---

**Addition:**

For your resizable panels to work, I recommend placing the entire required markup inside one column:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".panel-left").resizable({
    handleSelector: ".splitter",
    resizeHeight: false
  });
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
}

.page-header,
.page-footer {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.panel-left {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 210px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}

.splitter {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 18px;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  min-height: 120px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.panel-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
  xtouch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/src/jquery-resizable.js"></script>

<body class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column px-0">
  <div class="page-footer p-2">HEADER</div>
  <main class="row flex-fill no-gutters flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col panel-container">
      <div class="panel-left">
        left panel
      </div>
      <div class="splitter">
      </div>
      <div class="panel-right">
        right panel
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <div class="page-footer p-2">FOOTER</div>
</body>
```

Comment: That is great! Solves the issue. Thank you. BUT the next step is to make column 2 and 3 re-sizable via this plug-in (https://codepen.io/rstrahl/pen/eJZQej) which requires .column02 to be flex: 0 0 auto. 
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dragontheory/nq5f4276/
How do I get around that? 
Is there a better way? Is there a similar plug-in that doesn't require flex: 0 0 auto?

Comment: @Dragon, see addition to answer.